# Enviar mais de um registro para um mesmo cadastro no Banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql

Possuo cadastro de dependentes com o form enviando corretamente para o BD.
Me deparei com o problema que não me atentei de que o trabalhador pode ter mais de uma dependente, gostaria de saber como posso adicionar mais de um dependente ao funcionário, crio mais campos para caso tenha outros dependentes mas como ficará e/ou enviará para meu BD e gravar junto com o funcionário?

Esse é meu código para adicionar dependente;

```
<tr>
<td>Tipo de Dependente:</td>
  <td><select name="tpDep" id="tpDep">
    <option></option>
    <option value="01">Cônjuge;</option>
    <option value="02">Companheiro(a) com o(a) qual tenha filho ou viva há mais de 5 (cinco) anos ou possua Declaração de União Estável;</option>
    <option value="03">Filho(a) ou enteado(a);</option>
    <option value="04">Filho(a) ou enteado(a), universitário(a) ou cursando escola técnica de 2º grau;</option>
    <option value="06">Irmão(ã), neto(a) ou bisneto(a) sem arrimo dos pais, do(a) qual detenha a guarda judicial;</option>
    <option value="07">Irmão(ã), neto(a) ou bisneto(a) sem arrimo dos pais, universitário(a) ou cursando escola técnica de 2° grau, do(a) qual detenha a guarda judicial;</option>
    <option value="09">Pais, avós e bisavós;</option>
    <option value="10">Menor pobre do qual detenha a guarda judicial;</option>
    <option value="11">A pessoa absolutamente incapaz, da qual seja tutor ou curador;</option>
    <option value="12">Ex-cônjuge;</option>
    <option value="99">Agregado/Outros;</option>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td width="69">Nome:</td>
  <td width="546"><input name="nmDep" type="text" id="nmDep" size="70" maxlength="70" />
    <span class="style1"></span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Data de Nascimento:</td>
  <td><input name="dtNascto" type="text" placeholder="DD/MM/AAAA" id="dtNascto" size="10" maxlength="10" />
         <small><small><i><span class="style1"></span></td></small></small></i>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td width="69">CPF:</td>
  <td width="546"><input name="cpfDep" type="text" id="cpfDep" size="15" maxlength="11" />
    <span class="style1"></span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Deduz IRRF?</td>
  <td><input name="depIRRF" type="radio" value="S" />
    Sim
    <input name="depIRRF" type="radio" value="N" />
    Não <span class="style1"></span> </td>
<tr>    
<td>Salário Família?</td>
  <td><input name="depSF" type="radio" value="S" />
    Sim
    <input name="depSF" type="radio" value="N" />
    Não <span class="style1"></span> </td>  
</tr>   
<tr>    
<td>Defic. Fisica ou Mental?</td>
  <td><input name="incTrab" type="radio" value="S" />
    Sim
    <input name="incTrab" type="radio" value="N" />
    Não <span class="style1"></span> </td>  
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

O ideal é ter uma tabela para o trabalhador e uma tabela separda só para os dependentes. Aí você utiliaza o `id` do trabalhador como chave estrangeira na tabela de dependentes.

Já na programação. Você permite a adição de um número de dependentes de forma fixa (3 por exemplo) ou dinâmica, com um botão "Adicionar Dependente" que através de javascript adiciona campos no próprio formulário de cadastro do trabalhador. Ou uma rota separada específica só para o cadastro de dependentes após o cadastro do trabalhador.

De qualquer forma, você terá de fazer 2 querys de `INSERT`, uma para o trabalhador e outra para cada dependente tendo como chave estrangeira de trabalhador, o trabalhador cadastrado anteriormente.

Comment: Obrigado David, parei aqui e pensei na mesma coisa, fazer separados, será o melhor caminho mesmo. Muito obrigado!